# Is there a name for this property of a subset of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, terminology

Let $F$ be a field with the addition $(x,y) \mapsto x+y: F^{2} \to F$; let $A \subset F$ be nonempty; and let $(P)$ be this property of $A$: for every pair of $x,y \in A$ we have $x+y \notin A$. 
For instance, if $F := \mathbb{R}$ and if $A :=$ the set of all odd integers, then $A$ satisfies $(P)$.

I wonder if there is any name for $(P)$ in literature, most probably in Algebra literature?

Comment: If  $F$  is  a  field ,  is it  even   possible  that  $x+y \in F$  but  $x+y \notin F$  $?$

Comment: @user118494: Thanks for detecting it. That is my typo.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Indeed; I corrected the gross mis-language.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Please be referred to the example I supplied, if you are still interested. :)

Comment: @GudsonChou, you may be referring to [sum-free sets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sum-FreeSet.html).  But I may be wrong.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris: Thank you. It looks a neighboring property.